# Not all log levels are being logged in Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I have an application set up to use Application Insights, and I'm trying to manually log some custom information. Here's my controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private ILogger<MyController> Logger { get; set; }

    public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger)
    {            
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Logger.LogCritical("Test critical");
        Logger.LogError("Test error");
        Logger.LogWarning("Test warning");
        Logger.LogInformation("Test information");
        Logger.LogDebug("Test debug");
        Logger.LogTrace("Test trace");

        ...
    }
```

I have this in my Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Warning);
    ...
```

}

And this in my Program.cs:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

And in my appsettings.json:

```
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
}
```

When I look in Application Insights in my Azure portal, the only things logged are:

[image]

So it's skipping a few for some reason, and only logging Critical, Warning, and Error. I'd mainly like to use `LogInformation`.

Is there something I need to change in my Logging settings or maybe in the Startup file?

Comment: Hello Steven, I just want to check if the issue can be solved as per the answer below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to collect all telemetry data, you should not specify `Warning` logLevel in `appsettings.json`. The `Warning` log level will only collect the `Warning` / `Error` / `Critical` data, but abandon the `Trace` / `Debug` / `Information` data.

For more details, please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#control-logging-level) and this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-level).

Please specify the log level of application insights as `Trace` in `appsettings.json`, like below:

```
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace"
    }
  },
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem, and our solution was to set a filter to `LogLevel.Trace`, and match the filter category with the `ILoger` category. More info in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/492274/filter-logging-for-azure-application-insights).

We notice that by default only `Warning` / `Error` / `Critical`, is sent to Application Insights. To remove this restriction is needed to specify a filter with a valid category.

We can define a rule for all categories like:

```
logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace);
```

This can be dangerious in production cause will cause masive amounts of logs. We can just disable this default behaviour only for a `ILogger` class specifying a category, the convention is to use the class name as category like this:

```
logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Mynamespace.MyController", LogLevel.Trace);
```